# Containers Orchestations and some docker functions

Tags: docker, containers, orchestration

I am familiarizing with the architecture and practices to package, build and deploy software or unless, small pieces of software.

If suddenly I am mixing concepts with specific tools (sometimes is unavoidable), let me know if I am wrong, please.

On the road, I have been reading and learning about the images and containers terms and their respective relationships in order to start to build the workflow software systems of a better possible way.

And I have a question about the services orchestration in the context of the docker :

- The containers are lightweight and portable encapsulations of an environment in which we have all the binary and dependencies we need to run our application. OK
- I can set up communication between containers using **container links** `--link` flag.

I can replace the use of container links, with docker-compose in order to automate my services workflow and running multi-containers using `.yaml` file configurations.

And I am reading about of the Container orchestration term, which defines the relationship between containers when we have distinct "software pieces" separate from each other, and how these containers interact as a system.

Well, I suppose that  I've read good the documentation :P

My question is:

A docker level, are **container links** and `docker-compose` a way of container orchestration?

Or with docker, if I want to do container orchestration ... should I use `docker-swarm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should forget you ever read about container links.  They've been obsolete in pure Docker for years.  They're also not especially relevant to the orchestration question.

Docker Compose is a simplistic orchestration tool, but I would in fact class it as an orchestration tool.  It can start up multiple containers together; of the stack it can restart individual containers if their configurations change.  It is fairly oriented towards Docker's native capabilities.

Docker Swarm is mostly just a way to connect multiple physical hosts together in a way that `docker` commands can target them as a connected cluster.  I probably wouldn't call that capability on its own "orchestration", but it does have some amount of "scheduling" or "placement" ability (Swarm, not you, decides which containers run on which hosts).

Of the other things I might call "orchestration" tools, I'd probably divide them into two camps:

1. *General-purpose system automation tools* that happen to have some Docker capabilities.  You can use both Ansible and Salt Stack to start Docker containers, for instance, but you can also use these tools for a great many other things.  They have the ability to say "run container A on system X and container B on system Y", but if you need inter-host communication or other niceties then you need to set them up as well (probably using the same tool).
2. *Purpose-built Docker automation tools* like Docker Compose, Kubernetes, and Nomad.  These tend to have a more complete story around how you'd build up a complete stack with a bunch of containers, service replication, rolling updates, and service discovery, but you mostly can't use them to manage tasks that aren't already in Docker.

Some other functions you might consider:

- *Orchestration*: How can you start multiple connected containers all together?
- *Networking*: How can one container communicate with another, within the cluster?  How do outside callers connect to the system?
- *Scheduling*: Which containers run on which system in a multi-host setup?
- *Service discovery*: When one container wants to call another, how does it know who to call?
- *Management plane*: As an operator, how do you do things like change the number of replicas of some specific service, or cause an update to a newer image for a service?

Comment: With respect to Networking, docker links are just an old way to communicate between containers. I've seen recently the bridges concept ...